Frequency of Crystal
I recently started working with a PIC18F board which has the following oscillator on it. My calculations indicate that it is a 16 Mhz oscillator but simulation points at 48 Mhz. If anyone can shed any light on it I would be grateful. ]1

That's obviously a 20.000MHz crystal. I have no idea what made you think otherwise.

Oh I don't know probably the fact that my calculations don't match? Anyways thanks for your input

Can you show the configuration of the oscillator in your software?

I'm not sure how to do that I'm a new PIC user.
To explain why i am doing this: I wrote a code for toggling a pin every time a timer rolls over and with no prescaler in 16 bit mode it rolls over every 5.46 ms. I used that to estimate my uC oscillator frequency to be 65536/(5.46e-3)=12 Mhz. Now how should i proceed?
I guess i should go over to the Microchip forum now as this is the wrong place to ask :)

The crystal is 20.000 MHz. The PIC18F4550 has a clock circuit that allows various crystals to be used to get the required frequency for the USB interface and for the clock. For example, it can be divided by 5 and then multiplied to 96MHz then divided by 2 to get 48MHz. The CPU clock can be derived from the 96MHz (divided by 2, 3, 4 or 6) or it can be the crystal frequency divided by 1, 2, 3 or 4. Or it can use the secondary oscillator or the on-chip RC oscillator, depending on the requirements.


That's a 20.000 MHz crystal.
However, depending on how your board or MCU and software works, it might run at any frequency while using the crystal as reference frequency for a PLL, or it might not even use the crystal in any way and run with internal clocks.

Crystals almost always have the exact frequency written on them, in this case 20.000 meaning 20MHz.
The text in the lower left corner is usually the brand, I think MEC stands for MEC Quartz. (Which is apparently a Hong Kong manufacturer of crystals with subpar datasheets and a broken web site.)
This would be a low profile HC49 package with through-hole mounting.
As for PIC, they are known to often use various internal clock multipliers/PLLs. You'll have to read the oscillator/system clock chapter of the friendly manual to find out how your part works.

Thanks this is really helpful!
